# How to close all windows in Matlab in a GUI created programmatically?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have two windows 'parent' and 'child'. I'd like to press the close button in the 'parent' GUI and close both windows 'parent' and 'child'.

My callback function is the next:

```
function close(hObject, eventdata)
    close all;
end
```

My code for the 'figure' object is:

```
set(hMainFigure, 'deletefcn', @close);
```

Both windows are closed, but I get the next error:

```
Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N)
to change the limit.  Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can
crash MATLAB and/or your computer.

Error in main/close

Error using delete
Error while evaluating figure DeleteFcn
```

With my second option is the same:

```
function close(hObject, eventdata)
    close(hParentFigure);
    close(hChildFigure);
end
```

I'd like to know why the error is triggered?

Note: Each GUI is programmed on different files. I am not using GUIDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have pressed the close button on the "parent" figure, it's already being closed.  No need to close it again.  In your second implementation, (the one without "close all"), try removing the `close(hParentFigure);` line.

As @Huguenot already pointed out, this recursion limit is triggered by the window close activities re-firing the window close activities.

---

A more robust recommendation is recommended in the error detailed error message.  Just use `delete` instead.  Here is some demonstration code:

```
deleteAllFigures = @(~, ~) delete(findobj(0,'type','figure'));    
for ix = 1:4
    h = figure;
    set(h,'DeleteFcn',deleteAllFigures);
end
%Now press the close box on any of the figures.
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using now: delete(findobj(0,'type','figure'));

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be reproduced with

```
f = figure;
set(f, 'deletefcn', @(src, evt)close('all'))
close all
```

However, in 2013a you get a slightly more informative warning

```
Warning: A callback recursively calls CLOSE.  Use DELETE to prevent this message. 
> In /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/toolbox/matlab/graphics/close.p>request_close_helper at 167
  In /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/toolbox/matlab/graphics/close.p>request_close at 253
  In /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/toolbox/matlab/graphics/close.p>close at 124
  In @(src,evt)close('all')
  In closereq at 18
  In /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/toolbox/matlab/graphics/close.p>request_close at 256
  In /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/toolbox/matlab/graphics/close.p>close at 124
```

What's probably happening is that when you call `close all`, that function tries to call `delete` on the figure with the custom `deletefcn`.  Because the figure hasn't finished closing, when the `deletefcn` is executed `close all` will try and delete the same figure again and so on.

Comment: Thanks, so explanatory!